# How to access nested elements in json in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

This is the json data structure used in flutter

```
flutter: {
    "members": [
        {
            "firstName": "Michael"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jennifer"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Lisa"
        }
    ]
}
```

To access the above data I used the below code

```
var parsedData = json.decode(state.successResponse);
                    var name = parsedData['members'];
```

I am not able to access the inner field of `firstName` in the above json.
How should I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `parsedData['members'][pos]['firstName']`? Please show what you're trying to do

Comment: @ClaudioRedi No I didn't tried that, but when I implemented your suggestion, it's giving error for `pos` as it not defined, how you define `pos`?

Comment: `members` is an array so you need an index to access it.. `pos` is your index, you need to define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `members` is JSON Array you can convert it to dart `List` type and then you can operate on the list (adding, removing, accessing elements by index).
You can do something like this -

```
  List members = parsedData['members'];
  
  //You can access members by index
  print(members[1]); //prints {firstName: Jennifer}
  
  print(members[1]['firstName']); //prints Jennifer
  
  //Or you can iterate over the list
  members.forEach((member){
    print(member['firstName']);
  });
```

Hope this helps!